# Separate Differing values into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that looks something like

```
StudentName | Grading Type | AssignmentName | Grade Given
John Doe    | Exam         | Exam 1         | 90.2
John Doe    | Exam         | Midterm        | 87.0
John Doe    | Homework     | Week 1         | 75.0
John Doe    | Homework     | Week 2         | 100.0
Jane Doe    | Homework     | Week 1         | 100.0
...           ...            ...              ...
```

And I want to get the average of the grade given per grading type as columns for each student, how do I go about this? See below for sample/desired output

```
StudentName | Exam | Homework 
John Doe      89.0   88.7
Jane Doe      77.0   100.0
```

Realize this is a dramatic oversimplification of the dataset I'm talking about and a case statement would involve upwards of 60 cases, So I'm looking for something that actually partitions it into new columns based on the controlled type. I do understand the avg function --I'm hoping there's some function whose intricacies I have missed. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Jane Doe has no exam, so how did you get 77?

Comment: It's a sample dataset. I had hoped one could get that there's more...but I'll add "..." to the bottom of the first "table"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    StudentName
  , Exam = avg(case when GradingType = 'Exam' then GradeGiven end)
  , Homework = avg(case when GradingType = 'Homework' then GradeGiven end)
from t
group by StudentName
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/VMB21085

returns:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| StudentName |   Exam    |  Homework  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Jane Doe    | NULL      | 100.000000 |
| John Doe    | 88.600000 | 87.500000  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

---

For a dynamic `pivot()`:

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max);
declare @sql  nvarchar(max);
  select @cols = stuff((
    select distinct 
      ', ' + quotename(isnull(nullif(GradingType,''),'unknown'))
      from t 
      order by 1
      for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'')
select  @sql ='
 select StudentName, ' + @cols +'
  from  (
    select StudentName, GradingType, GradeGiven
      from t
    ) as t
 pivot (avg(GradeGiven) for GradingType in (' + @cols +')) p'
select @sql
exec(@sql);
```

generates the following code:

```
select StudentName, [Exam], [Homework]
  from  (
    select StudentName, GradingType, GradeGiven
      from t
    ) as t
 pivot (avg(GradeGiven) for GradingType in ([Exam], [Homework])) p
```

and returns:

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| StudentName |   Exam    |  Homework  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
| Jane Doe    | NULL      | 100.000000 |
| John Doe    | 88.600000 | 87.500000  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: I was hoping I could avoid it. But if there's no other way...I will write the 60+ cases actually required by my dataset.

Comment: @Archaimot Added a dynamic pivot to avoid having to determine all of the `GradingType`

Comment: I appreciate it--I have been avoiding exec(@SQL) due to a separate system, backended in SQL not working well with that command--that said thank you for your contribution!

Comment: @Archaimot Even if you do not want to `exec` the created query, it will create the query for all `GradingType` as shown with `select @sql`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT StudentName, [Grading Type], [Grade Given] FROM MyTable) SRC
    PIVOT( AVG( [Grade Given] ) FOR [Grading Type] IN ([Exam],[Homework])) PVT
```

Comment: Follow up question: what if I dont want to specify each type? I just want in(*) 

I tried a select statement as defined on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp  but it wasn't allowed.

Comment: For using `PIVOT` you have to specify every `Grading Type`. If it is unstable or you only want to see used ones or you don't want to write all of them. You have to create pivot query dynamically. You can see an example at the answer of @SqlZim.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `PIVOT` command to do this.

Something like this should achieve what you want...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Schoolwork;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Schoolwork
(StudentName varchar(128), GradingType varchar(30), AssignmentName varchar(30), GradeGiven decimal(4,1));
INSERT dbo.Schoolwork (StudentName,GradingType,AssignmentName,GradeGiven)
VALUES 
('John Doe','Exam','Exam 1',90.2 ),
('John Doe','Exam','Midterm',87.0 ),
('Jane Doe','Exam','Exam 1',77.0 ),
('John Doe','Homework','Week 1',75.0 ),
('John Doe','Homework','Week 2',100.0),
('Jane Doe','Homework','Week 1',100.0);

SELECT * 
FROM (
        SELECT s.StudentName,
               s.GradingType,
               s.GradeGiven 
        FROM dbo.Schoolwork AS s
      ) AS src
      PIVOT (avg(src.GradeGiven) FOR GradingType IN ([Exam],[Homework])
      ) AS pvt;
```

(I took the liberty of adding Jane Doe's exam result to the test data).